# Optimizing add data from list to dynamic list using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I recently came across the need to be able to allow a user to select a value from a select list, and have it dynamically displayed in an unordered list and have the value disappear from the unordered list. The use then needed to be able to click and remove the row, which would then allow the value to reappear in the select list. Finally there is allow the possibility that there could already be data existing in the rows and I needed to be able to return (back to my controller) an array of ids along with whether they are being removed or added to the database (which is the reason for the hidden inputs). I'm trying to update my JavaScript skills, any help on what I can do better/optimize, would be very helpful.

HTML:

```js
$('#AddValues').click(function() {
  $('#select2 :selected').each(function() {
    // alert($(this).text() + " : " + $(this).data('value2'));
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
      var rcId = $(this).val();
      $(this).hide();

      if ($('#groupItem' + rcId).length) {
        $('#groupItem' + rcId).show();
        $('#rc_' + rcId + '__Remove').val("false");
      } else {
        addValues($(this).text(), rcId, $(this).data('value2'), $(this).data('value3'), $(this).data('value4'));
      }
    }
  });
});

$('body').on('click', '.removeRow', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var hiddenValue = $(this).next().val();
  $('#select2 option[value="' + hiddenValue + '"]').show();
  $('#groupItem' + hiddenValue).hide();
  $('#rc_' + hiddenValue + '__Remove').val("true");

});

function addValues(rcName, rcValue, dataValue2, dataValue3, dataValue4) {
  $("#tbList").append(
    $('<li/>', {
      'class': 'list-group-item justify-content-between',
      'id': 'groupItem' + rcValue,
      text: rcName
    })
    .append(
      $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'label label-default',
        text: dataValue2
      })
    )
    .append(
      $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'label label-default',
        text: dataValue3
      })
    )
    .append(
      $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'label label-default',
        text: dataValue4
      })
    )
    .append(
      $('<a/>', {
        'class': 'removeRow'
      })
      .append(
        $('<i/>', {
          val: '',
          'class': 'remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white'
        })
      )
    )
    .append(
      $('<input/>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        'id': 'rc_' + rcValue + '__Name',
        val: rcValue
      })
    )
    .append(
      $('<input/>', {
        type: 'hidden',
        'id': 'rc_' + rcValue + '__Remove',
        val: 'false'
      })
    )
  );
}
```

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.removeRow {
  float: right;
}

.removeRow {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

a:hover.removeRow {
  color: #bbb;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="select2" multiple="true" class="form-control">
      <option value="0" data-value2="1.0" data-value3="2.0" data-value4="3.0" style="display:none;">default</option>
      <option value="1" data-value2="1.1" data-value3="2.1" data-value4="3.1">The Sky</option>
      <option value="2" data-value2="1.2" data-value3="2.2" data-value4="3.2">The Ground</option>
      <option value="3" data-value2="1.3" data-value3="2.3" data-value4="3.3">The Sea</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="AddValues" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Values">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul id="tbList" class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" id="groupItem0">
        default
        <span class="label label-default">10</span>
        <span class="label label-default">20</span>
        <span class="label label-default">30</span>
        <a class="removeRow"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
        <input type="hidden" id="rc_0__Name" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" id="rc_0__Remove" value="false" />

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using array notation for your data properties, as this will clean up your `data-value1`, `data-value2`, `data-value*` anti-pattern and a lot of your javascript code.  I would always take a step back and revisit your solution when you find yourself naming variables, element id's, data properties, etc. in this manner.  This is almost always an anti-pattern that suggests you should be using an array.  That might make your option HTML look like this:

```
<option value="0" data-values="[1.0,2.0,3.0]" style="display:none;">default</option>
```

The nice side-benefit to this is that now your solution becomes scalable for any number of data elements.

---

Of course the above approach has ramifications on your javascript.  For example, your `addValues()` function might need to look like this:

```
function addValues(rcName, rcValue, dataValues) {
  $li = $('<li/>', {
    'class': 'list-group-item justify-content-between',
    'id': 'groupItem' + rcValue,
    text: rcName
  });    
  dataValues.forEach(function(value) {
    $li.append(
      $('<span/>', {
        'class': 'label label-default',
        text: value
      })
    );
  });
  // not shown - continue building li here

  // append at the end
  $('#tbList').append($li);
}
```

Again, this code is now scalable for any number of data values (and shorter).

I would also consider de-nesting your `li` construction from the `$('#tbList').append()` operation as I have done in the example above.  I think this make the whole thing easier to read/understand.

---

You can probably address the same name* anti-pattern in your HTML element ID's.  You probably should not have to worry about dynamically generating id names.  Instead, just apply a class to all these elements and use data-properties on the elements to provide references between elements.

---

You should cache jQuery selectors that you are going to be using repeatedly, rather than repeatedly querying the DOM.

---

Don't use `alert()` for debugging (it looks like you did this at one point due to your commented-out line).  Use `console.log()`. This allows you to dump debug information without actually impacting the way the UI works.

---

Do you **really** need to attach your onclick handler to `<body>`?  If there is some other common ancestor for all these elements (`div.container` for example) you should attach this behavior there so you are not checking this event bubbling condition every single time a click happens on the page, even in unrelated areas.

---

**UPDATE**

To answer your question about how to get rid of your anti-pattern around id properties.  Consider an `<li>` element that looks like this:

```
<li class="list-group-item justify-content-between" data-option-value="0">
```

Here you set a data-property to link this `li` back to the `option` element with that value.  This gets you out of the world of having to build id's via concatenation or split apart id strings to get target `option` you are interested in.  This provides two-way link between these elements.  So in the option context you could do something like:

```
// get target li from selected option
// here this would refer to option
// optVal would take place of your current rcId variable
var optVal = $(this).val();

// in addValues you would do this:
$('<li/>', {
    'class': 'list-group-item justify-content-between',
    'data-option-value': optVal,
    text: rcName
  })
```

From `li` context you would determine target `option` like this:

```
var hiddenValue = $(this).data('option-value');
$('#select2 option[value="' + hiddenValue + '"]').show();
```

Comment: Very Interesting. Thank you for your input. I will admit there is no rhyme or reason to how I wrote it, beyond getting it to work based off what I found on line. Scalability is my number one concern. After I posted this, I realized that I only added 3 data values, when there will be 7.... I will try using your changes and see how well they work. Also, when you say I shouldn't have to worry about generating Ids, do you mean the groupItem? if so, how would I know which one to "remove"?

Comment: @Chillie Please see update to my answer.

Comment: It looks like I would also need to add  $('[option-value="'+rcId +'"]'); to my $('#AddValues').click() function, because the groupItem no longer exists.

Comment: @Chillie Yes. You would need to use the data property in the selector.  One thing you might also consider is building a mapping (say in a javascript object) of `option`s to `li`s to avoid unnecessary repeated DOM queries.